# Program exits instantly, not allowing to debug

Tags: c++, windows

My code, which used to work on Windows 8.1, and works on another Windows 10 system, now doesn't work at all on Windows 10 after the update. I get no error whatsoever, the code just instantly exits. When I run it from console, I get nothing and instant close on the software.

```
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'G:\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cbw64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcomp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcamp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'G:\AllDLLs\fanndoubled.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\PS5000a.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cufft64_65.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'G:\AllDLLs\blas_win64_MT.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'G:\AllDLLs\lapack_win64_MT.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10240.16384_none_0212ec7eba871e86\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10240.16384_none_0212ec7eba871e86\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\PicoIpp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10240.16384_none_0212ec7eba871e86\comctl32.dll'
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvapi64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvapi64.dll'
'MyProject.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll'
The thread 0x1c3c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1f30 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1130 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[0x1BF8] MyProject.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Any idea what I should look out for?

Comment: isn't that a link problem ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: How do the pdb files cause this? I highly doubt this is a duplicate as listed, why would I need the pdb files for Windows DLLs? Sometimes I wonder if people read through the issue at all.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I would like to urge @πάνταῥεῖ to not get involved in a questions, that clearly don't fall into their field of expertise. This is not the first time this happened. It's rather a fairly frequently recurring pattern.